# Start Google Assistant/ Google now with a voice action command

Tags: android, wear-os, google-now, google-assistant-sdk

Is there any way of starting the Google assistant voice input prompt with one of the built-in system actions: like **Start timer** or **Set alarm**, and then have the user complete the action with voice?

Basically I would like a button in my app that bypasses "Ok Google" and "Set timer" and instead straight goes to letting the user configure the action.

This is for Android Wear but I would expect it's the same for a phone.